# What is the issue with my soft power switch circuit?

Tags: power-supply

I have an issue with my soft power switch circuit. The original design is made by Sparkfun, it's an experimental circuit they made and they don't sell it. Most likely because of issues.

It's a soft power switch, click it once and the power turns on. The switch is connected via GPIO to the MCU which will turn itself off if the power wasn't held long enough. Software wise it works perfectly. But hardware wise it's doing strange things.

Having the whole circuit powered down and just let it sit. It turn on every 20ish seconds, thanks to the software in the MCU it will shut down again. But if that software was not present it would stay on.

So my question is why and what can I change to make this works. Perhaps someone has a better circuit to offer? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct path to ground at the output.

If there is any leakage through Q2 or D5 it will slowly charge any capacitors on the output. If the output voltage gets to a high enough value to start turning on Q3 the circuit will switch on

Try putting a 10k resistor from the output to ground to divert any leakage current to ground without causing enough bias voltage to generate.

The actual resistor value will depend upon how much leakage is present. If only a small amount is present a higher value will be adequate and will consume less power during operation. I suggested 10k as that is the value of R18.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So to be sure, I should add a 10k from SUPPLY_EN to GND? :)

Comment: or 1M in parallel to D2 maybe? I have a feeling something gets picked up and charges the NMOS cap via D2. So 1M cap will force power sense to 0V when it's off, while it will have too much voltage drop when it's on and therefore D2 will provide the voltage. Or yeah 10k from supply EN to GND. To make sure the cap doesn't charge. Some path to GND needs to be

Comment: Ilya, 10k solution of 1M solution, which is the best or are they equally good? I have just now soldered the 10k and testing it, so far it seems to do the job!

Comment: @user2965339 - yes. The actual value for the initial experiment is just to determine the cause. If it does fix the problem you can then determine the optimum value. It is a compromise between correct operation and excessive power leakage during operation. As the other comments states a resistor across D2 will have the same effect as they are connected by R18.

Comment: @Kevin White, your solution works. I thank you for that. What value would you estimate roughly to be used? I might add that this circuit is powered by a LiPo 3.7V (boosted to 5V via DC-DC).

Comment: If you connected SUPPLY_EN to GND, the exact value doesn't matter too much. There just needs to be a path for the MOSFET gate to discharge. 10k-100k range feels OK. As long as you don't care about wasted microamps when this thing is ON, which is likely the case.

Comment: it depends upon how much leakage is present. A lower value will consume more power from the battery during operation. There should not be any significant leakage through Q2 or D5 so 1 megohm should be adequate. What circuitry is connected to the "FAST-OFF" input? Is there any leakage from there?

Comment: @Kevin White, FAST-OFF is connected directly to the MCU GPIO, nothing in between or on the way, just a direct path. MCU holds it HIGH to keep itself alive, and pulls it LOW to shut itself off. Perhaps a resistor to GND should be smart to have there as well?