# Forced shutdown doesn't work on my circuit - Why?

Tags: circuit-design

I have a push button circuit that turns on power to my PCB, the MCU on the PCB can shutdown the circuit as the switch is connected to GPIO. ON is done by the circuit itself, OFF is done by software. This works fine.

This circuit is also supposed to have forced shutdown. Here is the text about this from Sparkfun, who made the [initial circuit.](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/17870)

> The current design is good but has a few problems. The 22uF cap we used requires an override time of 13 seconds. Under normal operation, the system will power down as quickly as you define in the code (1-2s) so users will rarely experience this. But if the system locks up, 13s is a long time to wait. We've also seen a few edge cases (low load or no load) where the override cut-off occurs only after the button is held for >13s and then released. This is caused by shorting between the finger on the button and the near by capacitor. Using an external button allows the unit to power down correctly every time.

For me, the forced shutdown never works. Why is this and what can I do to perfect this circuit? Forced shutdown would be nice to have after about 7 seconds.

[image]

Comment: Show precisely the correct circuit and where your MCU connects i.e. don't show a switch and then, in words, some time later, say it is a GPIO line. What precisely does this mean `ON is done by the circuit itself`. Explain where the `fast off` connects. `OFF is done by software` - how? Very much related to this earlier question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/609112/what-is-the-issue-with-my-soft-power-switch-circuit

Comment: Earlier question was different and that issue has been solved thanks to help from you guys. ON and OFF works perfectly, I have been testing this rigorously this past week to ensure it. The MCU side of this is irrelevant. The question I am asking is why the forced shutdown doesn't work on the circuit. It is done by hardware and has nothing to do with the MCU itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved by me hiring an electrical engineer to find the issue. A diode was needed between the MCU and POWER_SENSE/CTRL.

The circuit is now fully working. Been testing it for about a month.